# XDocument extension method XPathSelectElement not found in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-core, .net-core

Porting old code to a new ASP.NET Core Web Application, `XDocument` extension method `XPathSelectElement()` is not found, and I believe I have included all needed references.

This project is using .NET Core 1.0.0-preview2-003131

My using statements define:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Example code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"example.xml");
var elem = doc.XPathSelectElement("/example/path");
```

NuGet package installed: System.Xml.XPath v4.3.0

However, the extension method is not found, giving compiler error:

> Code CS1061   'XDocument' does not contain a definition for
>   'XPathSelectElement' and no extension method 'XPathSelectElement'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'XDocument' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing something with `XDocument`, configuration, or XPath implementation?

Comment: Clearly missing NuGet Package: System.Xml.XPath.XDocument